# FTA proof not by contradiction

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have a simple (maybe not easy) question.

Is there a direct proof of Fundamental Theorem of Algebra? 
If there is not, can we conclude if it is possible to create one?

Comment: A proof using the Banach fixed point theorem should probably qualify. You an find such proofs discussed in a post in MathOverflow.

Comment: But BFT has no direct proof, right?

Comment: Pick any point, and consider the sequence of its iterates under the map whose fixed point you are looking for. You can show that it is a Cauchy sequence because the map is a contraction. Since the complex numbers is a complete metric space, this shows that there is a limit, and the limit is your fixed point.

Comment: Ok, but what about the uniqueness of this point, or this is not relevant in  the proof of FTA form MathOverflow?

Comment: The uniqueness is an immediate consequence of the fact that the map in the BFPT is a contraction. You should look up its proof, it is very simple!

Comment: The fixed point proofs that I see are also by contradiction.

Comment: http://msp.org/pjm/2000/196-1/pjm-v196-n1-p10-s.pdf might be relevant to your interests, though it goes rather deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using planar Brownian motion.

Let $p:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ be a non-constant polynomial. Then $\lim_{|z|\to\infty}|p(z)|=\infty$, so there exists $R>0$ such that if $|z|\ge R$ then $|p(z)|>1 $.

Two properties of a planar Brownian motion (call it $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$) are crucial: (i) it is recurrent, and in particular  for each $\epsilon>0$ the set of times $\{t: |B_t|<\epsilon\}$ is unbounded above, with probability 1; (ii) there is a (random) reparameterization of time $\tau(t)$ such that $p(B_{\tau(t)})$ is again a Brownian motion.

Combining (i) and (ii), it is true that with probability 1 there are times $t_1<t_2<\cdots$ with $|f(B_{\tau(t_n)})|\le 1/n$. Fix one sample point $\omega$ with this property. Then $z_n:=B_{\tau(t_n)}(\omega)$ satisfies  $|p(z_n)|\le 1/n$. In particular,  $|p(z_n)|\le 1$ so that  $|z_n|\le R$. The sequence $\{z_n\}$, being bounded, has a convergent subsequence$\{z_{n_k}\}$ with limit $z_\infty$, and then $p(z_\infty)=\lim_kp(z_{n_k})=0$.

Answer (score 3):

The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra is usually stated as follows:

> Every non-constant complex polynomial has a zero.

State it using the contrapositive as follows:

> If a complex polynomial has no zero, then it is constant.

Then this proof using Liouville's theorem is not by contradiction:

- If a complex polynomial $p$ has no zero, then $1/p$ is a bounded entire function.
- By Liouville's theorem, $1/p$ is constant and so $p$ is constant.

The [canonical proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)#Proof) of Liouville's theorem is not by contradiction.

Comment: But the Liouville's theorem has no direct proof ;)

Comment: @Maciej, this proof is direct: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis).

Comment: Ok, my mistake, sorry.

Comment: If you're doing a proof by contrapositive, then it's not a direct proof either.